# What is "Improvement in Signal-to-Noise ratio"?

Tags: image-processing

The SNR and PSNR are used to measure the quality of an image after the reconstruction! but what is ISNR (Improvement in Signal-to-Noise ratio)?  I have two images (with noise and without noise), then how do we calculate ISNR and PSNR of those images ?

Comment: Isn't that standard English? Peak means the highest over a certain time frame. Improvement means however much better it is after processing it somehow.

Comment: i agree with u paxdiablo , but I am trying to understand the two terms  when applied to  different images

Comment: @PSON: I'd assume you calculate of SNR of both, then `ISNR = SNR(second image) - SNR(first image)`

Comment: It is a measure for the difference between the original (f) and noisy (y) image, compared to the difference between the original (f) and the restored  image

Comment: http://bit.ly/ISNR-1FETkyP

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of this is the ISNR is the decibel-scale of the noisy SNR divided by the restored-image SNR.

```
snr = sum( sum( ( img1 - img2 ) .^ 2 );

isnr = 10 * log10( noisy_snr / restored_snr );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  ,getting to know !